# Add project with Deployment Assembly

Tags: java, maven, deployment, maven-assembly-plugin

I have 2 projects in Maven: opermain and operweb.

I add opermain to operweb

> Properties > Deployment Assembly > Add > Project

It's ok, but when I want to create object reference in operweb, it's not import opermain project's class.

How can I import classes in one project to other project with Deployment Assembly or I must write something in pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem adding dependency to pom.xml

> ```
>  <dependency>             
>  <groupId>az.nikoil.operlist</groupId>
>  <artifactId>opermain</artifactId>                    
>  <version>1.0.0</version>
>  <scope>compile</scope> 
>  </dependency>
> ```